# Python GetCh vs For Loop

Tags: python, for-loop, getch

I need help getting my conditional statement to look through array values using a For Loop.

I have the impression that it may because I'm not using b'X' as I am in the other two if statements, but I just can't figure out the right syntax to get this going, and I'm not even sure what the b is doing there anyway.

The R and X keystrokes do execute their code properly, but P, N, D, and Q which are checked as part of the FOR loop, do not.

```
Token = [['P',0,.01,"Penny"],['N',0,.05,"Nickel"],['D',0,.10,"Dime"],['Q',0,.25,"Quarter"]]

def GetKey(CoinIn): # Recieve a coin, update all total counts and values
    if CoinIn == b'R':     # Reset All Values and counts to 0
        for i in Token:
            i[1] = 0
    elif CoinIn == b'X':   # Exit Request
        return('X')
    else:                 # HERE IS WHERE THE CODE BREAKS
        for i in Token:
            if CoinIn == i[0]:
                i[1] += 1
```

For more context, [the entire project](https://github.com/nwautier/RPICoinCounter/blob/FeatureEnrichment/main.py) is open source on GitHub.

Comment: What do you mean by "get this going"? What exactly is not working and what is the desired behaviour? It's not clear to me how this should work.

Comment: I'll edit the question...  Basically, the R and X keystrokes execute the appropriate code, but P, N, D, and Q, do not.

Comment: But why should P, N, D and Q do anything at all since there's no specified behaviour for them in your code? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal

Comment: If CoinIn is not X or B, it should go to else, which does a For-Loop check against the first character in each element of Token.  When it matches, The 2nd element +=1.  Is this not a good way of attempting this?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this code works as expected, as noted by @BoarGules. If you haven't printed the output at any point as was suggested, then I'm curious as to what made you think this wasn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code works exactly as it should. But that depends on the input to `GetKey()`.

I added the following lines at the bottom:

```
GetKey('P')
GetKey('P')
print(Token)

GetKey('N')
GetKey('D')
print(Token)

GetKey('Q')
print(Token)
```

And I got this output:

```
[['P', 2, 0.01, 'Penny'], ['N', 0, 0.05, 'Nickel'], ['D', 0, 0.1, 'Dime'], ['Q', 0, 0.25, 'Quarter']]
[['P', 2, 0.01, 'Penny'], ['N', 1, 0.05, 'Nickel'], ['D', 1, 0.1, 'Dime'], ['Q', 0, 0.25, 'Quarter']]
[['P', 2, 0.01, 'Penny'], ['N', 1, 0.05, 'Nickel'], ['D', 1, 0.1, 'Dime'], ['Q', 1, 0.25, 'Quarter']]
```

If, on the other hand, you pass bytes not strings to `GetKey()`, like this:

```
GetKey(b'P')
GetKey(b'P')
print(Token)

GetKey(b'N')
GetKey(b'D')
print(Token)

GetKey(b'Q')
print(Token)
```

you will just see this line repeated:

```
[['P', 0, 0.01, 'Penny'], ['N', 0, 0.05, 'Nickel'], ['D', 0, 0.1, 'Dime'], ['Q', 0, 0.25, 'Quarter']]
```

That is because the coin codes in `Token` are the strings `'P' 'N' 'D' 'Q'`. If you compare them for equality with `b'P' b'N' b'D' b'Q'` the result will be `False`, so you need to change `Token` to look like this:

```
Token = [[b'P',0,.01,"Penny"],[b'N',0,.05,"Nickel"],[b'D',0,.10,"Dime"],[b'Q',0,.25,"Quarter"]]
```

I suppose there is a good reason, like hardware, for working with bytes instead of strings.

Comment: Thank you, this is a debug I haven't tried yet.  I will examine further.

Comment: Your edit has completely solved my issue.  To be honest, I'm not sure that I had a great reason to use bytes instead of strings...  It was recommended to me to solve an earlier issue, I think regarding case-sensitivity.  As a rather amateur programmer myself, I tend to trust anyone on SO with a higher rep than me, and figure I'll learn my lesson later.